# Autodesk Forge Viewer: CORS blocked, Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I have the following code:

```
const initOpts = {
  env: 'AutodeskProduction',
  // getAccessToken: onTokenRequest,
  accessToken: forgeAuthToken,
  api: 'derivativeV2',
};

Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(initOpts, handleViewerInit);
```

And update the viewer div with the following (React-based, this part loads the expected `div` with the loader, etc):

```
const viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(viewerRef.current)
const err = viewer.start();

const documentId = `urn:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6YnVja2V0LTk5OC8xMzQ0NDY0NjEyLmR3Zw`;
console.log('documentId', documentId);

Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(documentId, handleDocumentLoadSuccess, handleDocumentLoadError);
```

I've simplified the code a bit, as it uses React hooks etc, but regardless, the `Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load` method calls the error callback, which reports  401 with the following `developerMessage: "Access token provided is invalid or expired."`

---

On generating the access token, I've used the method below:

`forgeAuthToken` is received from a backend route, generated with the following:

```
const forgeRefreshToken = true;
const {
  FORGE_CLIENT_ID = "...",
  FORGE_CLIENT_SECRET = "...",
} = process.env;
const forgeScopes = [
  'data:read',
  'data:write',
  'bucket:create',
  'bucket:read',
  'bucket:update',
  'bucket:delete',
  'viewables:read',
];
const tokenAuth = new ForgeApis.AuthClientTwoLegged(
  FORGE_CLIENT_ID,
  FORGE_CLIENT_SECRET,
  forgeScopes,
  forgeRefreshToken,
);
const token = await tokenAuth.authenticate();
```

It's of the form:

```
{ 
  access_token: "<token>",
  token_type: "Bearer",
  expires_in: 3599,
  expires_at: Date Mon Sep 07 2020 11:59:42 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)
}
```

I've tried with more and less scopes to confirm that's not the issue, as I know it requires the `viewables:read` scope, but was unsure if the other scopes might affect that.

Note that I have replaced my development URL with `"$DEVELOPMENT_URL"` as I'm not following best security practices yet, but it's an EC2 public URL of the format `http://ec2-<public-ip>.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:<port>`

This is the same URL I have configured as both the callback and website URL on the Forge app control panel.

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at 
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/derivativeservice/v2/manifest/adsk.objects%3Aos.object%3Aasdfqwerff%2FLON-BH-NBH-B1-1020.dwg?domain="$DEVELOPMENT_URL". 
(Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
```

---

What am I doing incorrectly? I've followed both [this](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/viewer_basics/load-a-model/) and [this](https://forge.autodesk.com/developer/learn/viewer-app/understand-code), and now I'm out of ideas on what has failed

---

Bit more information, I've logged `Autodesk.Viewing.token` (of the form `eyJhb...9SkIs`), and decoded the JWT access token which gives the following, just to check this wasn't some instance problem with the way I've implemented the viewer's token:

```
{
  "scope":[
    "data:read",
    "data:write",
    "bucket:create",
    "bucket:read",
    "bucket:update",
    "bucket:delete",
    "viewables:read"
  ],
  "client_id":"<my-client-id>",
  "aud":"https://autodesk.com/aud/jwtexp60",
  "jti":"DJUX42Gdl6mYhbCF7d2iZUjvdmYuzZR5wQ2j2BdtjNhm7eAx4Ai26pBKrNFuTScd",
  "exp":1599479159,
}
```

So the viewer definitely has the token prior to viewing, which works for creating buckets, uploading objects, etc.

---

Per request, the headers from the pre-flight OPTIONS

**Request headers**

```
OPTIONS /derivativeservice/v2/manifest/dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6ZGFkcy8xMzQ0NDY0NjEyLmR3Zw?domain=http%3A%2F%2Fec2-<public-ip>.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com%3A3000 HTTP/1.1
Host: developer.api.autodesk.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
Referer: http://ec2-<public-ip>.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:3000/
Origin: http://ec2-<public-ip>.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:3000
Connection: keep-alive
```

**Response headers**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-ads-acm-namespace,Accept-Encoding,Content-Encoding,If-Match,x-ads-ul-ctx-oxygen-id,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,If-Modified-Since,Accept,x-ads-ul-ctx-caller-span-id,Expect,x-ads-ul-ctx-source,Content-Range,If-None-Match,x-ads-ul-ctx-workflow-id,x-csrf-token,Content-Length,x-ads-test,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials,Content-Type,x-ads-ul-ctx-client-id,Authorization,x-ads-acm-check-groups,x-ads-acm-groups,x-requested-with,x-ads-acm-scopes,x-ads-ul-ctx-head-span-id,x-ads-ul-ctx-scope,Session-Id,Range,x-ads-force,x-ads-ds-client
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST,GET,OPTIONS,HEAD,PUT,DELETE,PATCH
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://ec2-<public-ip>.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:3000
Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Mon, 07 Sep 2020 12:37:59 GMT
Origin: http://ec2-<public-ip>.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:3000
Referer: http://ec2-<public-ip>.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:3000/
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0
Vary: Origin
X-Forwarded-For: 188.214.12.163
X-Forwarded-Port: 443
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: Did you set out the proxy information on package.json or on weback to pass this url to the app.

Comment: @Suhirthan I don't control the server - would I still need to do that for a third-party API? I can access other methods of the API, eg creating a bucket or uploading an object, without any issue

Comment: That's odd, this should work  in that case. Maybe a better mind can suggest something better.

Comment: @Suhirthan Even stranger is that I am using the same API token to make those requests successfully. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After re-reading the request headers I noticed the Authorisation header was 'Bearer [object Object]'. I posted the entire credentials object, instead of the access token property. Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

A couple of notes:

- If the only thing you want to do is previewing your models in Forge Viewer, the `viewables:read` scope is sufficient
- I don't think you have to specify the `env` and `api` properties when initializing the viewer
- The "callback URL" is only relevant when you're using the 3-legged authentication, but in this case it looks like you're only using a 2-legged auth, right?

Now, a custom domain is fine, the viewer should pass it along when communicating with the Forge APIs. For example, when you go to https://forge-basic-app.herokuapp.com, open the Network tab in the dev tools, and filter all the requests containing "manifest" in them, you should see two requests: an OPTIONS request (the CORS "pre-flight" check) and an actual GET request for the derivative manifest. Both of these should include `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://forge-basic-app.herokuapp.com` in their response headers, indicating that the application on Heroku *is* allowed to request these resources.

Try looking at these requests in your application on AWS EC2, see if something is off there. Perhaps the domain query param isn't correct?

Comment: Hey Petr, I've removed the env and api, and tested with only the single scope. You're right about the two-legged auth, I just included the details in case they were important. What is the domain query param exactly that you're referring to? How is it set?

Comment: The OPTIONS XHR returns a 200 OK, and includes the origin, I'll post details in the question of req/res

Comment: Added the pre-flight details :) Any ideas? If there's a way I can privately send you the public IP. I'd be grateful if that makes it easier to debug